# Why doesn't MediaElement work in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement

When I run my Silverlight app, this code doesn't play a video at all:

```
    <MediaElement
        Source="winvideo-201DataGridPreview.wmv"
        AutoPlay="True"
        AudioStreamIndex="2"
        Margin="10"
        Height="200"
        Width="200"/>
```

From all of the examples I can find of MediaElement, it seems to be the correct syntax, etc.

Is there anything I'm forgetting?

Comment: Maybe the syntax is correct but there are problems finding the right codec or something that prevent the framework to play the media.

Comment: Are you sure the video file gets copied to the bin/Debug directory?

Comment: yes, I switched it to "copy always", I've trie a .avi file and a .wmv file, moved them to the root and tried them, always just blank, no sound. Hmmmm.

Comment: I've tried a .avi and .wmv file, any other ideas what works for sure without any special codecs?

Comment: Are you getting anything in the Output window when you F5 it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edward, based on your XAML check: 1) that the WMV file is in the appropriate encoding format, 2) that the WMV file is located alongside where your XAP file is (I'd actually check this first).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.  I added the wmv file as an existing object to my Silverlight project, and then on the properties of the wmv file, I set its build action to Resource.  Once I did this it would play for me.

Answer (score 2):

The referenced media files need to be in `ClientBin` folder. For Sliver-light 4.0 you may use not only `.wmv` but `.mp4` format as well.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case of unsupported mediafile.

These are supported (source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080(VS.95).aspx)

The MediaElement object supports the following formats. These encodings are supported regardless of the file name extension.

**Video**

- WMV1: Windows Media Video 7
- WMV2: Windows Media Video 8
- WMV3: Windows Media Video 9
- WMVA: Windows Media Video Advanced
- Profile, non-VC-1
- WMVC1: Windows Media Video Advanced
  Profile, VC-1

**Audio**

- WMA 7: Windows Media Audio 7
- WMA 8: Windows Media Audio 8
- WMA 9: Windows Media Audio 9
- WMA 10: Windows Media Audio 10
- MP3: ISO/MPEG Layer-3

  - Input: ISO/MPEG Layer-3 data stream
  - Channel configurations: mono, stereo
  - Sampling frequencies: 8, 11.025, 12, 16, 22.05, 24, 32, 44.1, and 48 kHz
  - Bit rates: 8-320 kbps, variable bit rate
  - Limitations: "free format mode" (see ISO/IEC 11172-3, sub clause 2.4.2.3) is not supported.

On really simple (but a bit brute force) way to test if your video file is Silverlight compatible is to upload it to [http://Silverlight streaming](http://streaming.live.com/) and it will tell you if it is ok or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same issue, I haven't found the right configuration that will reference the video file correctly. If I reference my video by source "vid1.wmv" and set it to content, it's packaged into the xap file but the video won't play.

As TimHeuer says, check the video file is in the same place as the .xap file.

If I **copy the video file** directly into the web project's **ClientBin**, it works.
That was the solution for me, but I'd really like to know how this should be done correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This was very annoying but found that if you right click on your media file and properties and set it to "Content" build action it will be included in the XAP, then you reference it with /myPic.jpg/wmv or /Images/myPic.jpg/wmv (depending on the structure of your project and vid or pic obviously). Hope this helps