# Cannot seek media element in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement, seek

This is the situation.

I have a MainPage.Xaml, within this MainPage.Xaml I have embedded a UserControl (VideoWidget.Xaml) (LayouRoot.Children).

VideoWidget.Xaml has a mediaElement embedded in its LayoutRoot.

I'm trying to Pause/Play the MediaElement (mediaElement1) from MainPage.Xaml but does not respond.

e.g.

```
public MainPage()
    {
        // Required to initialize variables
        InitializeComponent();            
        Video testVideo = new Video();

        VideoWidget video = new VideoWidget(testVideo);
        videoWidget.Height = 246;
        videoWidget.Width = 290;
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(video);
        video.mediaElement1.play();
      }
```

The All methods for mediaElement are not responsive.
Help please.

Mohit

Answer (score 0):

Try putting test control buttons inside the VideoWidget itself.  Does that work?  If so, there may be a problem with the way you are exposing the mediaElement in the VideoWidget as a public member.

Comment: hi Dave, I tried hardcoding the Pause method in the VideoWidget Constructor just after media.source = URI. Still no luck!

Comment: e.g. 
            mediaElement1.Pause();
            mediaElement1.Source = new Uri(video.fileLocation);
            mediaElement1.AutoPlay = true;        
            mediaElement1.Pause();

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478017/why-doesnt-mediaelement-work-in-silverlight